# How to configure Web role on Azure Compute Emulator to work like local IIS (static URL)

Tags: iis, azure

So, the question is how to configure Web role on Azure Compute Emulator to work like on local IIS? By this I mean, that, the web role have the fixed url (like you can in project properties set the "Use Local IIS Web server" and set the fixed url)?

How to set Azure Compute Emulator to work on static url or at least at static port?

Is is really annoying that everytime I start the web role I have different url (port)!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is that you cannot run it on a static port, but it should run on the first available port in its port range (starting at 80 and incrementing until it finds a free port). If it increments with every "debug" session starting, then it's because the previous emulator didnt teardown completely before you started a new one.

There are some ideas how to fix this issue here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/ae2df7e0-5005-4bcd-8b69-bb53323eb589

Comment: Yeah I know that it increments the port, but I do not want that. I want fixed port.

Comment: I tried using the instructions in the following post but it didn't work for me. Sharing in the hope that someone else can get it to work. Maybe I'm not understanding something: http://blog.syntaxc4.net/post/2011/01/06/Changing-the-Windows-Azure-Compute-Emulator-IP-Address.aspx

Comment: @Jason Rowe - this will only change the default binding of the dev fabric to give a different host header on startup. This means IIS can be made to listen to the binding on a different IP address, but unfortunately doesn't allow control of the port - that is related to the Load Balancer built into the Emulator BEFORE IIS becomes involved :-(

Answer (score 4):

Check out [this solution](http://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/windows-azure-compute-emulator-and-ports/) from Michael Collier [a fellow Windows Azure MVP]

Comment: Nice link, but this is not solution. This is just what is basically known. Azure emulator delegate a next free port to the running instance. I would like a fixed port to set to the azure instance.

Comment: this link did help me, it talks about turning off stuff that is using different ports, but also crucially for me, a hint from Wade Wagner around restarting the emulator completely "right-click on the emulator icon and select “Exit”"